# webshare on IIS

Tags: windows, iis-7

We want to offer some file storage capability in our asp.net 3.5 web app and would like users to map a drive to the webshare hosted on our IIS. this will allow users to simply copy files from their systems to the mapped [as a drive] web folder and save them the task of uploading files, etc. Any ideas on how we can implement a webshare capability on IIS 7.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll require an installation of WebDAV on your IIS server.

Instructions are available on this [WebDav tutorial site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/%5C)